# How to achieve repetitive full cycle imageview rotation with Android Java?

Tags: java, c#, android, rotation

I have an `ImageView` in my android application and a button to rotate the image left by 90 degrees progressively by each new click. Now the code I have handles the rotation of the object up to the original position before any rotation was applied, when I click on the rotate button again so the cyclic rotation effect continues, a weird rotation is applied to the object instead of rotating to the 90 degrees left of the current position, it does some weird rotation that can be confirmed by implementing this code below that am using and needs reforming...
The code is Android Java formatted in Xamarin Standards(`The methods start with uppercase letters`)

**Code**

```
private void Rotate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rotation_count += 1;
            //initialize the image transformation matrix
            /*
             we need four states for this rotation
            1 for 90
            2 for 180
            3 for 270 and 
            4 for 360 for full rotation
             
             */
            //I need help with this structure to make it implement the infinite
             //rotation to the left loop which means provided the user has clicked the 
             //rotate button it should keep adjusting the current position by 90deg
            if (rotation_count == 1)
            {
                imageView.Animate().Rotation(90f).Start();
            }else if(rotation_count == 2)
            {
                imageView.Animate().Rotation(180f).Start();
            }else if(rotation_count == 3)
            {
                imageView.Animate().Rotation(270f).Start();
            }
            else
            {
                imageView.Animate().Rotation(360f).Start();
                //reset the rotation_counter
                rotation_count = 0;
            }
            
        }
```

**Goal**

I want to achieve full cycle rotation of this ImageView object regardless the number of times the user clicks the button it should keep rotating 90 degrees to the left even after full cycle rotation is achieved, provided the  user clicks the button again, it should rotate the image 90 degrees to the left to create an infinite rotation loop triggered by the button click, Thank You.

Comment: C# but its Java classes and methods being used, the two languages inter operate on Xamarin Applications, for the java counterpart of my code, all the methods that follow the imagView object start with lowercase

Comment: If you inspect the method where the code is embedded, it has a C# signature ie `(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: If you post a Java solution, I can easily convert it to C# in the blink of an eye

Comment: Can you describe the weird rotation you mentioned?

Comment: As in after a full cycle rotation, you would expect that when a user clicks on the rotate left button again like he did initially then it should rotate the imageview by 90 degrees just like last cycle first click but its not doing that it rotates to some weird value

Comment: Try resetting the rotation to 0 when your reach 360 using `imageView.setRotation(0)`.

Comment: Trying that out in a moment

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work

Comment: Instead of keeping a `rotation_count` and rotating accordingly, would you be able to just rotate the image by 90 each click?

Comment: @user3170251, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to figure it out on my own I managed to come up with a workaround to this. Multiply the counter with the number degrees you wish to turn on every click.

```
private void rotate_click(object sender, EventArgs e){
.           rotation_count+=1;
            if (rotation_count > 0)
            {
                imageView.Animate().Rotation(rotation_count * 90).Start();
                
            }
}
```